# How to eliminate the duplicate records from the delimited file in Linux file (myfile_I.out: application/octet-stream; charset=binary)

Tags: linux, sorting, ksh

I'm trying to load the data from linux file(which contains duplicates,and the data is unloaded from source table)  to a table.

```
     mylinux file properties: 
     $ file -bi myfile_I.out
     application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

before loading the data to a table.I should delete the duplicates from the linux file.

My approach to delete the duplicates:

1. Unloaded the data from source table to temp file (TempeEX.out)
2. from TempEX.out file performed sort -u function and deleted the 
       duplicates and the final unique data records loading to myfile_I.out
3. Finally load the myfile_I.out data to a target_table

I am facing the issue in STEP 2 {Unable to delete the complete duplicates from TempEX.out file}

```
    #------------------------------------------------------------------#
    #- Delete the duplicates from TempEX.out write the unique data-----# 
    #------------------to myfile_I.out----------------------------------#

    echo -e "Eliminate the duplicates from the ${FILE_PATH}/TempEX.out 
    file" >> ${LOG}

    sort -u  ${FILE_PATH}/TempEX.out > ${DEST_PATH}/myfile_I.out

    echo -e "Unique records successfully written into 
    ${DEST_PATH}/myfile_I.out" >> ${LOG}

    count=0
    while read
    do
    ((count=$count+1))
    done <${DEST_PATH}/myfile_I.out
    echo -e "Total No of unique records in ${DEST_PATH}/myfile_I.out:" 
    ${count} "\n" >> $LOG
     #-----------------------------------------------------------------#
```

Actual Results:

```
   Counts:

    $wc -l TempEX.out myfile_I.out
    196466 TempEX.out  -->#File Contains duplicate records#
    196460 myfile_I.out-->#Unique records after my approach(sort -u)# 
    392926 total
```

I did some sort functions to know the duplicates present in myfile_I.out
Duplicate record count in TempEX.out file

```
    $ cut -d'^X' -f1,6,10 TempEX.out|sort|uniq -d|wc -l
    5
```

Duplicate record count in myfile_I.out file

```
    $ cut -d'^X' -f1,6,10 myfile_I.out|sort|uniq -d|wc -l
    1
```

Got which records(on primary_key) having duplicates in TempEX.out file

```
    $ cut -d'^X' -f1,6,10 TempEX.out|sort|uniq -d|cat
    701234567      412345678        19
    701234568      412345677        18
    709875641      412345859        17
    701234569      425984031        21
    701234570      409845216        20
```

Got which records(on primary_key) having duplicates in myfile_I.out file

```
    $ cut -d'^X' -f1,6,10 myfile_I.out|sort|uniq -d|cat
    709875641      412345859        17
```

Expected Results:
To eliminate the duplicates from TempEX.out file an load the unique data to myfile_I.out.

```
    sort -u TempEX.out > myfile_I.out /*cant resolving the issue*/
```

Can we do something like this?(perform up on primary keys)

```
    sort -u -f1,6,10 TempEX.out > myfile_I.out
```

Comment: Way too much information, but up vote because you have really tried to solve your problem and you have included code! Yes you can use `keys` while sorting a file to reduce to unique values, but test it like crazy because the results often don't work as you expect/want them to. the correct syntax is `sort -t{yourFieldChar} -k 1 +k1 -k6 +k6 -k10 +k10 -o outFile infile` (but I don't have time to dbl-check this). `man sort` can help, but also search the inteweb for complex examples of using `sort` (hard to search here as the search function doesn't understand options). All IMHO. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your response @shelter 
command worked  to sort up on primary keys
**command to sort up on primary keys and load the sorted data to final file**
`sort -t"^X" -k1,1 -k6,6 -k10,10 -o TempEX.out TempFinal.out`
Now I perform sort -u and uniq -u to delete duplicate data both not working for my scenario
'sort -u TempFinal.out > Tempsheltter.out'
' wc -l TempFinal.out Tempsheltter.out
 196460 TempFinal.out
 196460 Tempsheltter.out
 392920 total' same resuluts got for uniq -u too 
** how to delete 1 duplicate record by giving primary key as condition?**

Comment: oops, I meant to include the `-u` option in my sample `sort` command. That will be the best I can offer. Good luck.

Comment: And again, I'll warn you, test like crazy because the results often don't work as you expect/want them to. Good luck ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little script that might help. It won't modify the original file with the new data, but create a new file to load (I always prefer to keep the original in case of errors). It's doing its verification on the primary key, but will ensure that in case of a duplicate primary key that the other columns are also the same. The rational being that, even if you don't mention it, there could be modification of existent data or errors from the input system. Anyways, the script will send those lines in a different file for the user review.

It's written in the comments, but just to be sure, no field in any column should have a value with blank space.

```
#!/bin/ksh

TIMESTAMP=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")

#No sense to do anything if the files are not readable.
if [[ ! -r $1 || ! -r $2 ]]; then
    print "ERROR - You must provide 2 parameters : 1 = path/filename of DB content 2 = path/filename of New Data"
    exit
fi

#Declaring 2 associative matrix
typeset -A TableDB
typeset -A DataToAdd

#Opening the different files. 3 and 4 for reading and 5 and 6 for writting.
#File handlers : 
# 3 for the data from the DB, 
# 4 for the new data to add, 
# 5 to write the new data to load (unique and new), 
# 6 to write the data in problem (same primary key but with different values)
exec 3<$1
exec 4<$2
exec 5>Data2Load_${TIMESTAMP}.txt
exec 6>Data2Verify_${TIMESTAMP}.txt

#Loading the 2 matrix with their data. 
#Here it is assumed that no field in any column contain blank spaces.
#Working with only 3 columns as in the example
while read -u3 a b c && read -u4 d e f; do
        TableDB[$a]=( $a $b $c )
        DataToAdd[$d]=( $d $e $f )
done

#Checking for duplicate and writting only the new one to load without the lines in possible errors
for i in ${!DataToAdd[@]}; do
        if [[ -z ${TableDB[$i]} ]]; then
                print -u5 "${DataToAdd[$i][0]} ${DataToAdd[$i][1]} ${DataToAdd[$i][2]}"
        elif [[ ${DataToAdd[$i][1]} != ${TableDB[$i][1]} || ${DataToAdd[$i][2]} != ${TableDB[$i][2]} ]]; then
                print -u6 "${DataToAdd[$i][0]} ${DataToAdd[$i][1]} ${DataToAdd[$i][2]}"
        fi
done

#closing the different files
exec 3>&-
exec 4>&-
exec 5>&-
exec 6>&-
```

Hope it helps !